# Editing pages from outside the Control Pane with two group id's

Tags: control-panel, login

{if author_id == logged_in_member_id OR logged_in_group_id == "1"} Edit This Page ⇑{/if}

I have added a second logged in group id "6" However, when I change this from 'logged_in_group_id == "1"' to 'logged_in_group_id == "1|6"'

it don't work…

how do I make this so both id == "1" and id == "6" can login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding another OR should work:

```
{if author_id == logged_in_member_id OR 
    logged_in_group_id == "1" OR  
    logged_in_group_id == "6"
} 
    Edit This Page ⇑
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you @Siebird! I'd posted from my phone and there aren't formatting options.